# Is there a way to shorten the variable value text in conditionals or in general in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir

I'm new to Ruby and I am building a web scraper. I have a variable that is assigned a value if a conditional is true.

The problem is that the value of the variable is really long and I'd like to avoid repeating myself with these long values.

I am using conditionals because the number of data that exists is not a static figure.

```
    #Grab the top 3 comps if they exist
        #comp1
    if b.element(:xpath => '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[13]/span').exists?
        comp1 = b.element(:xpath => '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[13]/span')
    end
        #comp2
    if b.element(:xpath => '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[13]/span').exists?
        comp2 = b.element(:xpath => '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[13]/span')
    end
        #comp3
    if b.element(:xpath => '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[13]/span').exists?
        comp3 = b.element(:xpath => '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[13]/span')
    end
```

Is there a way to decrease it the length of that such as

```
if "telement with really long xpath location on the webpage that we are checking to see if it is true ".exists?
    x = "That conditional referenced above"
end
```

Comment: If the string doesnt change why not to save it into variable ?

Comment: Does the website you are scraping utilise classes for elements, or ids? If yes, you can shorten the accessor that way. Something like ".//span[@class='className']"

Comment: @sonic there is a very slight difference - its `tr[1]`, `tr[2]` and `tr[3]`.

Comment: @benjessop, it does, but for some reason they aren't doing the trick. Could it be something to do that this data is displayed with AJAX? I prefer to use IDs or other kinds of tags when the data is static, like text fields or check boxes and wha not.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're just replacing a single number in that long xpath selector you can use a template string:

```
elements = (1..3).map do |x|
  b.element(
   xpath: '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[%d]/td[13]/span' % x
  )
end.select(&:exists?)
```

See [Kernel#sprintf](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) for the options which are pretty much identical to the venerable C sprintf function.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. lol. Brilliant! Thanks! I'm always looking for ways to reduce the lines of code I write!

Answer (score 1):

Break up the string, either literally, or logically:

```rb
# literally
table_xpath = '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table'

if b.element(:xpath => "#{table_xpath}/tbody/tr[1]/td[13]/span").exists?
  #...
end
```

```rb
# logically
table = b.element(xpath: '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table')

if table.element(xpath: "tbody/tr[1]/td[13]/span").exists?
end
```

break it up as many or as few times as you feel like to make the code read well.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly write WATIR CODE as shown below, you have to use `elements` instead of `element`

```
b.elements(:xpath => '/html/body/form/div[3]/div[6]/table/tbody/tr/td/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr')
    .take(3)
    .map{|tr|tr.element(xpath: "./td[13]/span")}
```

But still, the above code is not optimized, you can write the below code Once you located the table, For the below code, I assume the table number is 2.

```
b.table(index: 2)
.rows
.to_enum
.take(3)
.map{|row| row.cell(index: 13).span}
```

Comment: Will `.take(3)` return an error if there are less than 3 items? Sometimes, there are 0. Sometimes, there is 1. Sometimes more.